# Difference between npm library kafka-node and kafka-streams

Tags: node.js, kafka-node

In a project, Node.js application connects to Kafka message queue and get all messages from queue. I searched and found two packages **kafka-node** and **kafka-streams**. Which package will be suitable here?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node

https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-streams

Answer (score 0):

Both libraries would do, the question is if you want to do stream processing or just access the messages and do the processing in your custom code.
The simple client would be easy and streightforward. The streams version offers more features for real time processing and aggregation but has a steep learning curve!